# How do I exclude allocations in a tight loop from ASAN?

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703206), it was discovered that using recent versions of GNU libstdc++ to read a series of numbers from [a space-separated human-readable file](https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/ww15mgh.grd.z) ([mirror](https://gitlab.com/drmoose/why-does-gccs-ifstream-double-allocate-so-much-memory/-/blob/follow-up-asan-question/ww15mgh.grd.xz)) causes a ton of allocations, scaling linearly with the size of the file.

Given the file linked above and this test program:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::ifstream ww15mgh("ww15mgh.grd");
    double value;
    while (ww15mgh >> value);
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind `--tool=memcheck` reports:

```
==523661==   total heap usage: 1,038,970 allocs, 1,038,970 frees, 59,302,487
```

Because each of those million allocations is immediately freed before `operator>>` returns, there are no leaks and the actual memory footprint of the program in a release build is tiny (81KB). But, compiling with `-fsanitize=address` turns that mass of allocations into a Real Problem.

Here's the total memory footprint of the above program, running with and without ASAN:

```
$ g++ stackoverflow.cpp -o _build/stackoverflow
$ /usr/bin/time -v _build/stackoverflow |& grep 'm r'
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3512
```

```
$ g++ stackoverflow.cpp -o _build/stackoverflow_asan -fsanitize=address
$ /usr/bin/time -v _build/stackoverflow_asan |& grep 'm r'
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 125196
```

125MB doesn't seem like a huge problem, but in the context of a much larger unit test program running on an embedded ARM board and calling this function several times, it ran my ARM CI environment out of memory.

**A workaround for this specific case**

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::ifstream ww15mgh("ww15mgh.grd");
    double value;
#if defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__) && (defined(__GLIBCXX__) || defined(__GLIBCPP__))
    std::string text;
    while (ww15mgh >> text)
        value = std::strtod(text.data(), nullptr);
#else
    while (ww15mgh >> value);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Using this preprocessor gate yields a much more manageable total memory footprint:

```
$ g++ stackoverflow_workaround.cpp -o _build/stackoverflow_workaround_asan -fsanitize=address
$ /usr/bin/time -v _build/stackoverflow_workaround_asan |& grep 'm r'
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 6396
```

Which is because neither libstdc++'s `operator>>(ifstream&, string&)` nor glibc's `strtod` have superfluous allocations in them, as can be seen by tricking the workaround to run under valgrind:

```
$ g++ stackoverflow_workaround.cpp -D__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./a.out |& grep 'total heap'
==2483624==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 81,368 bytes allocated
```

[Sample Code](https://gitlab.com/drmoose/why-does-gccs-ifstream-double-allocate-so-much-memory/-/tree/follow-up-asan-question) and [CI Pipeline Results](https://gitlab.com/drmoose/why-does-gccs-ifstream-double-allocate-so-much-memory/-/jobs/963483686) for this are available on gitlab.

At this point my CI is no longer running out of memory and crashing, so my co-workers can carry on with their lives. I, however, feel like hiding stuff from the sanitizer with `#ifdef __SANITIZE_ADDRESS__` is somehow cheating.

**The Question**

Is there a way to make the original program run under ASAN, but skip ASAN's allocator padding just for the duration of the `operator>>` call? In the general case, of a tight loop calling a third-party function that allocates memory, how do I avoid an enormous memory footprint with `-fsanitize=address`?

Comment: Wait, wait, are you using **Valgrind** and **Address Sanitizer** at the same time? Why? When you have address sanitizer you do not need Valgrind.Valgrind was useful before compiler deliver tooling to detect errors.

Comment: No, I'm not using them at the same time. The valgrind heap allocation reports in the question were all made on binaries without `-fsanitize=address` turned on, and are only included to explain why the address sanitizer runs out of memory when executing the test program under gnu libstdc++.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, AddressSanitizer will delay the reuse of freed memory, to help catch use-after-free errors.  This feature is called "quarantine", and the amount of memory used for it is configurable at runtime, see https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags.  So for example, if you set the environment variable `ASAN_OPTIONS` to `quarantine_size_mb=4` before running your program, it should limit the amount of memory used to 4 megabytes.

This is not specific to the call in question, so it doesn't exactly address what you asked, but I think it will solve your underlying problem of "how to use AddressSanitizer on a machine with low memory".